# R: How to model Stochastic and deterministic trends in ARIMA?

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, forecasting, arima

I have annual time series data from 2000 to 2020. The brand has introduced new marketing camping in 2010 and I want to investigate the impact of this policy, that's why I am trying to explore the trend. In case of monthly data I would decompose it into seasonality and trend components but I only have annual data and that's an issue.

```
library(forecast)

year <- c("2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", 
"2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", 
"2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020")
sales <- c(21524785976, 20788220636, 20103157749, 23266090815, 
28135206873, 30621196496, 35219067283, 38372121399, 41400013521, 
31744808119, 40970654696, 49762785203, 48477334132, 50052144873, 
53705925977, 48359389061, 46836934926, 50341098361, 54225979785, 
53706776803, 50864932473)

df <- data.frame(year, sales)

#Create time series
df.ts <- ts(df[,c("sales")],start=c(2000))
```

Now I want to obtain Stochastic and deterministic trends as given on this [link](https://otexts.com/fpp2/stochastic-and-deterministic-trends.html). however when I apply it there is `ARIMA(0,0,0)` instead of `ARIMA(2,0,0)`.

```
#Apply Stochastic trend
trend <- seq_along(df.ts)
(fit1 <- auto.arima(df.ts, d=0, xreg=trend))
Series: df.ts 
Regression with ARIMA(0,0,0) errors 

Coefficients:
        intercept        xreg
      20009874233  1810698122
s.e.   1036863859   101903292

sigma^2 = 1.973e+19:  log likelihood = -495.25
AIC=996.5   AICc=997.91   BIC=999.63
```

The same happens in case of a deterministic trend, there is `ARIMA(0,1,0)`  instead of `ARIMA(0,1,1)` and consequently output is different.

```
#Apply deterministic trend
(fit2 <- auto.arima(df.ts , d=1))

Series: df.ts 
ARIMA(0,1,0) 

sigma^2 = 2.104e+19:  log likelihood = -473.31
AIC=948.62   AICc=948.84   BIC=949.62
```

Could you explain why it happens? **Also, which algorithm/technique could you suggest (besides Moving-Average) in order to investigate the impact of the campaign? I am open to discussion.**

Answer (score 0):

**tldr;** You don't have enough data for the optimal model to be anything other than a white noise model with a linear trend.

---

It helps to visualise the residual data when we subtract the trend from the `sales`.

```r
fit <- lm(sales ~ year, data = df %>% mutate(year = as.integer(year)))
df %>%
    mutate(
        year = as.integer(year),
        sales_res = sales - predict(fit)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(year, sales_res)) + 
    geom_line()
```

[image]

The residuals are consistent with white noise:

```r
auto.arima(ts(sales - predict(fit), start = 2000))
#Series: ts(sales - predict(fit), start = 2000) 
#ARIMA(0,0,0) with zero mean 
#
#sigma^2 = 1.785e+19:  log likelihood = -495.25
#AIC=992.5   AICc=992.71   BIC=993.54
```

As to the difference between your models with a deterministic & stochastic trend, we need to take a step back:

1. You don't difference data if you expect a deterministic trend. So if you assume a data generating process `y_t = c + beta * t + ARMA(p,q)` (i.e. an ARMA process with a *deterministic* trend) you would *not* difference data.
2. You only difference data if you assume a *stochastic* trend.

In other words, if you can model the trend explicitly, there's no need to difference the data.